# Handling Secrets in EKS, better design

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, amazon-eks, argocd

I have the following situation for which I am looking for a solution.

•   I am deploying an application to EKS.

•   While I deploy, I use ARGOCD, GitHub, and Jenkins.

•   The deployment is Active / Passive.

•   I start the passive deployment by triggering the Jenkins pipeline for it. As part of my passive pipeline, I push in secrets in the namespace for the EKS cluster.

•   I rolled out changes from ARGO reflecting Github manifest to passive.

•   Passive runs fine.

•   A pod in Active is recycled as part of some events.

•   This pod now takes the secrets from EKS Namespace.
•   These have changed after the passive install.

•   Active pods never come up as the change for them to use the secrets is still in githops; passive works fine, but active is now broken.

•   How can this situation of handling secrets be designed better?

Comment: Why are the active and passive deployments using the same secrets?

Comment: There is a rotation on secrets , so the difference.

Comment: So the deployment purpose is to rotate the secrets? Can the old secret live in parallel to the new secret until the deployment completes?